# Returned gameScore Parse.Object object from Parse.Query.get documentation gives undefined gameScore object

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform

Directly from [Parse.com javascript guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects):

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.get("xWMyZ4YEGZ", {
  success: function(gameScore) {
    // The object was retrieved successfully.
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
  }
});

var score = gameScore.get("score");
var playerName = gameScore.get("playerName");
var cheatMode = gameScore.get("cheatMode");
```

Basically gives Uncaught ReferenceError: gameScore is not defined...

Here is my code to troubleshoot this:

```
// Retrieve class
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore"); //redefine the GameScore class based on the cloud.
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
var my_object;
var some_object = query.get("SQV1DZXv5p", {
    success: function(gameScore) { //gameScore is the retrieved object.
        alert('Object retrieved, with object ID: ' + gameScore.id);
        //document.getElementById('division1').innerHTML = gameScore.id; 
        my_object = gameScore.id;

    }, 
    error: function(object, error) {
        alert('Retrieval FAILURE, error: ' + error.message + '; Object retrieved instead is: ' + object); //object will be NULL if not found.
    }
});

var score = gameScore;
document.getElementById('division1').innerHTML = my_object;
```

So this still throws the reference error for `gameScore`.
Also, the `document.getELementById` statement does not print the `gameScore.id` in my `division1` div. It remains empty. But when I check to see what `my_object` is in the javascript console, it returns the `gameScore.id` correctly.

What's interesting is if I run the `document.getELementById` line *inside* the success function, then it will display the `gameScore.id`...

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.get("xWMyZ4YEGZ", {
  success: function(gameScore) {
    // The object was retrieved successfully.
    var score = gameScore.get("score");
    var playerName = gameScore.get("playerName");
    var cheatMode = gameScore.get("cheatMode");
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
  }
});
```

`gameScore` is only be available in the scope of the success block, hence the Uncaught ReferenceError. The world outside the success block does not know it exists. Do your stuff in there.

Also, `.get()` makes a request from the server, so it would take time to complete. Performing operations `gameScore` after the `.get()` method will result in accessing that object when it has not been fetched yet, hence another error. See @danh's comment below. For network calls like this, always perform actions on the fetched object inside the completion block.

Comment: Another way to put it, code that appears before .get() runs first, code that appears after .get() runs second before the network request starts, and code that appears in the success function runs third, after the network request finishes.

Comment: Thanks guys. New to this network concept but crystal clear.