# Parse Query equalTo not Working

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to simply query my database filtering results with a parameter (named: "lesson")  I've just obtained from another query.
The problem is that when I try to print with an "alert" command lesson's value it says: undefined. 
It is wierd that when I put "lesson" inside a tuple's field it works.
In particular line 
`obj.set("student", lesson);`
added just for debugging purpose, actually writes a consistent value into the table.
This is the whole code:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("checkingTwoTables", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var stud,lesson;


//select first student of the list and check for his enters
var wholeTable = new Parse.Query("enter");
wholeTable.find({
    success: function(result) {
        if(result.length != 0)
        {               
            //pick student name and lesson we're interested in
            stud = result[0].get("student");                
            lesson = result[0].get("lesson");
        }
        else {}

    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("failed");
    }
});



alert("lesson value:" + lesson);
var selectionQuery = new Parse.Query("enter");

selectionQuery.equalTo("lesson", "cns");
selectionQuery.find({
    success: function(results) {

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
            {
                var obj = results[i];
                obj.set("raggiunto", 77);
                obj.set("student", lesson); // <<-------HERE IS THE ISSUE
                obj.save(null,{
                  success: function (object) { 
                    response.success(object);
                  }, 
                error: function (object, error) { 
                  response.error(error);
                }
              });
            }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("failed");
    }
}); //code continues...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302215/returned-gamescore-parse-object-object-from-parse-query-get-documentation-gives/31302902#31302902) exact issue.

`.find()` is making a request with the server. You cannot guarantee when it would finish thus you cannot guarantee that your second query will run after the first one completes. Therefore, when your second query runs, the value of `lesson` may still have not been retrieved yet by the first query, hence the "undefined".

The solution would be to move the second query inside the `success` block of the first query.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i've done and it works perfectly!
For those who has the same problem: I could not find a way to avoid this nesting.

Have a nice day.

Comment: You could avoid the nesting... Read up on Promises on the Parse documentation: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises